# How to propagate domains filtering on variables using Google Or-tools?

Tags: java, constraint-programming, or-tools

I want to use Google Or-tools to apply the interactive configuration. Therefore, I need to know how to apply constraints propagator to filter variable domains.

For example, suppose the following program:

```java
CpModel model = new CpModel();

// Create variables x and y
IntVar x = model.newIntVarFromDomain(Domain.fromValues(new long[]{1, 2, 3, 4}), "x");
IntVar y = model.newIntVarFromDomain(Domain.fromValues(new long[]{1, 2, 3, 4}), "y");

// Tuple constraint 
model.addAllowedAssignments(new IntVar[]{x, y}, new int[][]{{2, 1}, {2, 4}});

// Equality constraint
model.addEquality(x, 2);

CpSolver solver = new CpSolver();
```

Well, I know that executing solving algorithms over this smallest problem is fast. However, as this problem gets bigger and bigger, the solving will turn out very expensive. What I need, in this specific moment, is to apply filtering algorithms to tightening the variable domains based on constraints.

More specifically, I would like to continue the program doing the following operations:

1. How to propagate filtering algorithms over variables domains? Something like: `solver.propagate()`?
2. How to enumerate variable domains? I would expect some result like:

```java
System.out.println(x.getBuilder().getDomainList()); // Should print x = [2]
System.out.println(y.getBuilder().getDomainList()); // Should print y = [1, 4]
```

Comment: While i don't want to rule out that ortools offers this functionality in a somewhat usable form, i would be afraid 1) about the Java interface not being complete enough (compared to the C++ core) and 2) things getting messy in a more complex workflow including refutation, conflict-analysis and backtracking. Of course the functionality is there (as it's the core of doing *solving*), but the documentation and stability (core changes) of this tools is far away from [gecode](https://www.gecode.org/) for example (where i can confirm easy treatment of above; but it's more or less C++ only).

Comment: If doing interactive propagation only (i don't get your full workflow yet), i doubt there is much to gain from ortools and i would at least consider alternatives like aboves gecode or choco (if you need java). In my opinion, ortools shines more in the *solving-process* because of learning/conflict-analysis (CP-SAT hybrid) and pretty heavy *automatic search* and *automatic algorithmic portfolios* (LP relaxation; maxSAT-techniques and so on)

Comment: And to add more comment-section pollution: if *interactive configuration* means high-frequency (non-manual) usage (like propagation-based techniques within some heuristic), then you will probably spend more time for java/c++ interface overhead (java is probably one of the worst languages to mix with c/c++ when performance is needed; more or less everything needs to be copied) than for propagation (of course this depends on what you exactly propagate).

Comment: Thanks, your advice is very relevant to me. Because I'm implementing an interactive configuration, the propagation engine is very important.
For now, I've researched the best technology to use in this project. I already compared three constraint technologies: Minizinc, Choco, and Or-tools.

Comment: Minizinc is a very interesting one, it provides a friendly way to post constraints and have a good documentation. However, it doesn't provide access to propagation, variables domains, and object-oriented modeling.

Choco-solver presents itself as the most usable one. It provides propagation, explanations, solving, and allows modeling in an object-oriented fashion (Java).

Ortools is very popular, supported by Google, and has good results in minizinc challenge. During the research, I didn't find many examples related to how to use the capabilities of Ortools for interactive configuration.

Comment: Based on your response, my expectations are confirmed. I guess that, for the interactive configuration problem, the choco-solver is the most suitable one. The criteria I used are based on the following items: 1) licensing, 2) domain filtering, 3) variables and constraint dynamic creating (GCSP), 4) constraints types supported, 5) explanations of inconsistencies, 6) programming language and 7) event notification.